# PHP printing using some MySQL connection isn't working well, is there a better way?

Tags: php, printing, citrix

I get these labels for a doctor's office and they have to be printed. Printing is done via a custom C# Outlook right-click calendar menu add-in and so the local printers aren't used. Also, this PHP setup was established long before my time and isn't getting rewritten for the client.

The `ArrivalHelper.php` system calls the script below, "PrintersMgmt.php" and then calls `PinnaclePDO.php` to connect to a MySQL instance running on an Ubuntu server to find an office location (in this instance locID is 2) and then finds the printer in that MySQL table and what server (cc-fp2, in this instance) that hosts it and sends that information back to print.

I need to find a way to do this better. I thought about using JavaScript to open a print dialog box, but I have no idea how to implement that here. Can someone give a PHP noob some pointers?

```
<?php

class PrintersMgmt {
  const PRINT_ALL_LABELS    = 0x1;
  const PRINT_ONE_LABEL     = 0x10;
  const PRINT_PASSPORT      = 0x100;
  const PRINT_REFERRAL      = 0x1000;

  const PRINTER_TYPE_LETTER = 1;
  const PRINTER_TYPE_LABEL  = 2;

  const
    ARRIVAL_URL = 'http://localhost/arrival.php';

  const QUERY_GET_PRINTER_BY_LOC_TYPE =
    'SELECT * FROM LocationPrinters
     WHERE locID = :loc AND printerType = :type
     ORDER BY printerPriority
      LIMIT 1';

  private $dbh;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->dbh = new PinnaclePDO();
  }

  public function getByLocationType( $loc, $type ) {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare( self::QUERY_GET_PRINTER_BY_LOC_TYPE );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':loc', $loc );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':type', $type );
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetch();
  }

  public function printPassport( $locId, $hin, $date, $userName, $method ) {

    $printFlags = $this->getPrintFlags($method);
    $referral = ( ! ($printFlags & self::PRINT_REFERRAL) == 0 );
    $passport = ( ! ($printFlags & self::PRINT_PASSPORT) == 0 );

    $printer = $this->getByLocationType( $locId, 1 );
    if ( $printer ) {
      $cmd = '.\firefox.exe';
      $args = sprintf(
         ' -print "%s?method=%s&hin=%s&user=%s&referral=%d&passport=%d"' .
         ' -printprinter "\\\\' . $printer[ 'printerHost' ] . '\\' . $printer[ 'printerName' ] .'"',
        self::ARRIVAL_URL, 'listconfirmed',
        $hin, urlencode( $userName ), $referral, $passport
        );

      if ( isset( $_GET[ 'debug' ] ) ) {
        print "Print with args: '$cmd $args'<br/>";
      }

      chdir( "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox2/" );
            shell_exec($cmd.$args);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public function printLabel( $locId, $hin, $date, $method ) {

    $printFlags = $this->getPrintFlags($method);
    $printer = $this->getByLocationType( $locId, 2 );
    $number = ( ( $printFlags & self::PRINT_ONE_LABEL ) == 0 ) ? 'all' : 'one' ;
    $cmd = 'LabelPrinter.exe';
    $args = sprintf(
       ' /print %s %s "%s" %s',
       $hin, $date, $printer[ 'printerName' ], $number );

    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'debug' ] ) ) {
      print sprintf( 'Printing \'%s\' labels \'%s %s\'<br/>',
              $number, $cmd, $args  );
    } else {
      chdir( "C:/Program Files/(truncated)/(truncated) Tools" );
      shell_exec( $cmd . $args);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public function getPrintFlags( $arriveMethod ) {
    $printFlags = 0x1101;
    switch ( $arriveMethod ) {
      case 'arrive':
        $printFlags =
          ( self::PRINT_ALL_LABELS
              | self::PRINT_PASSPORT
              | self::PRINT_REFERRAL );
        break;
      case 'reprintpassport':
        $printFlags = self::PRINT_PASSPORT;
        break;
      case 'reprintreferral':
        $printFlags = self::PRINT_REFERRAL;
        break;
      case 'reprintlabel':
        $printFlags = self::PRINT_ONE_LABEL;
        break;
      default:
        $printFlags = null;
    }
    return $printFlags;
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You're not happy with the current approach for printer selection, but I don't think you have explained why. Would you elucidate? I take it the web server sends the job to the correct printer host via the LAN? You can't use the browser's print dialogue as far as I know, as there is no way of using JavaScript to specify which printer to use.

Comment: The problem is that they want to use a print dialog box, and I'd be okay with just letting them select from the redirected printers in the Citrix session. When I try to add a printer to the MySQL table, things break. I could go on and on about what's wrong with this system, but in the end, i just need them to be able to open a print dialog box instead of allowing it to select a printer. I am a PHP noob. I know enough to be flexible and can learn more, but the print from PHP resources I've found don't tell me enough of what I need to know to make it print using the Windows dialog box.

Comment: Righto, there's a Citrix session involved. Would you edit your question to explain how that is used here? It feels like a critical detail (especially if you are printing through that at present). You need not "go on and on" in your question, but a description of how things are breaking if you do things in MySQL is probably important (and maybe there is an easy fix!).

Comment: Okay, so when I add a new printer to the locationprinters table in MySQL, the printer no longer prints from the Citrix session- which is using this script. However, if you use the printer installed on a PC as a network printer from the local machine, it works fine. I've restarted IIS Admin Service on the server this runs from and is hosted on, I've restarted Apache and killed the firefox process it uses to run from. For some reason, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, so the script runs in a Citrix session, and then starts one of the binaries mentioned (LabelPrinter or Firefox), tries to print from that, and fails? If you do the same without the script (i.e. use one of those binaries to print via Citrix manually) I presume that fails also? If so, it's likely not a PHP problem.

Comment: (When replying to individuals here, please use their name e.g. @halfer otherwise your comment is likely to get missed).

Comment: @halfer: It works when you print via Firefox manually, or when you print during the Citrix session. It is only when you print via the script that it seems to fail.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Maybe can you edit your question with the command line that gets passed to `shell_exec()`?